# Problem with authenticating in laravel when using dynamic route configurations

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, jwt, middleware

I use JWT authentication for my laravel api middleware group. Here is my route configuration:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']], function() {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('test', 'AuthController@test');
});
```

This code works well and I can't have unauthorized access to `test` method of my AuthController class:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['jwt.auth'])->except('login');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        //...
    }

    public function test()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

but when I change the route config to identify controller's methods name dynamically (as you see in the following code snippet), the authentication does not work anymore and I can access `test` method without bearer token!

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']], function() {

    Route::post('/{controller}/{method}', function ($controller, $method) {

        $controllerClass = 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\'.$controller.'Controller';
        if(method_exists($controllerClass, $method))
        {
            $controller = App::make($controllerClass);
            return $controller->callAction($method, array());
        }
        return abort(404);
    });
});
```

Any idea?